# TitleView bug I don't understand

Tags: java, android, eclipse, textview

I am working on a coursera course and I am really getting to the point where I think I am not really up for this field of work (development) and should stick to graphic designing. at least i want to finish this course but i keep getting bugs I don't understand! according to `logcat` there is a problem with the following line

```
titleView.setText(toDoItem.getTitle());
```

But for the life of me cant see the problem! Below is the full program if you need anything just tell me.

### ToDoManagerActivity

```
package course.labs.todomanager;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Priority;
import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Status;

public class ToDoManagerActivity extends ListActivity {

private static final int ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST = 0;
private static final String FILE_NAME = "TodoManagerActivityData.txt";
private static final String TAG = "Lab-UserInterface";

// IDs for menu items
private static final int MENU_DELETE = Menu.FIRST;
private static final int MENU_DUMP = Menu.FIRST + 1;

ToDoListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create a new TodoListAdapter for this ListActivity's ListView
    mAdapter = new ToDoListAdapter(getApplicationContext());

    // Put divider between ToDoItems and FooterView
    getListView().setFooterDividersEnabled(true);

    // TODO - Inflate footerView for footer_view.xml file
    //TextView footerView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.footerView);
    //LayoutInflater inflitrate= getLayoutInflater();
    //inflitrate.inflate(R.id.footerView, getListView());
    TextView footerView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null);
    // NOTE: You can remove this block once you've implemented the assignment
    //if (null == footerView) {
    //  return;
    //}
    // TODO - Add footerView to ListView
    ListView viewer= getListView();
    viewer.addFooterView(footerView);

    footerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.i(TAG,"Entered footerView.OnClickListener.onClick()");

            //TODO - Implement OnClick().
            Intent addone= new Intent (ToDoManagerActivity.this, AddToDoActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(addone, ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST);
        }
    });

    // TODO - Attach the adapter to this ListActivity's ListView
    viewer.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Log.i(TAG,"Entered onActivityResult()");

    // TODO - Check result code and request code
    // if user submitted a new ToDoItem
    // Create a new ToDoItem from the data Intent
    // and then add it to the adapter
      if (requestCode == ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
      {
          ToDoItem toDoItem = new ToDoItem(data);
          mAdapter.add(toDoItem);
      }
}

// Do not modify below here

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Load saved ToDoItems, if necessary

    if (mAdapter.getCount() == 0)
        loadItems();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Save ToDoItems

    saveItems();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_DELETE, Menu.NONE, "Delete all");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_DUMP, Menu.NONE, "Dump to log");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_DELETE:
        mAdapter.clear();
        return true;
    case MENU_DUMP:
        dump();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void dump() {

    for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        String data = ((ToDoItem) mAdapter.getItem(i)).toLog();
        Log.i(TAG,  "Item " + i + ": " + data.replace(ToDoItem.ITEM_SEP, ","));
    }

}

// Load stored ToDoItems
private void loadItems() {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        String title = null;
        String priority = null;
        String status = null;
        Date date = null;

        while (null != (title = reader.readLine())) {
            priority = reader.readLine();
            status = reader.readLine();
            date = ToDoItem.FORMAT.parse(reader.readLine());
            mAdapter.add(new ToDoItem(title, Priority.valueOf(priority),
                    Status.valueOf(status), date));
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null != reader) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

// Save ToDoItems to file
private void saveItems() {
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                fos)));

        for (int idx = 0; idx < mAdapter.getCount(); idx++) {

            writer.println(mAdapter.getItem(idx));

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null != writer) {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

### AddToDoActivity

```
package course.labs.todomanager;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Priority;
import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Status;

public class AddToDoActivity extends Activity {

// 7 days in milliseconds - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
private static final int SEVEN_DAYS = 604800000;

private static final String TAG = "Lab-UserInterface";

private static String timeString;
private static String dateString;
private static TextView dateView;
private static TextView timeView;

private Date mDate;
private RadioGroup mPriorityRadioGroup;
private RadioGroup mStatusRadioGroup;
private EditText mTitleText;
private RadioButton mDefaultStatusButton;
private RadioButton mDefaultPriorityButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_todo);

    mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    mDefaultStatusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.statusNotDone);
    mDefaultPriorityButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.medPriority);
    mPriorityRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.priorityGroup);
    mStatusRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.statusGroup);
    dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
    timeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);

    // Set the default date and time

    setDefaultDateTime();

    // OnClickListener for the Date button, calls showDatePickerDialog() to
    // show
    // the Date dialog

    final Button datePickerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.date_picker_button);
    datePickerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDatePickerDialog();
        }
    });

    // OnClickListener for the Time button, calls showTimePickerDialog() to
    // show the Time Dialog

    final Button timePickerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.time_picker_button);
    timePickerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showTimePickerDialog();
        }
    });

    // OnClickListener for the Cancel Button,

    final Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Entered cancelButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");

            // TODO - Indicate result and finish
             Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED,returnIntent);
                finish();
        }
    });

    // TODO - Set up OnClickListener for the Reset Button
    final Button resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
    resetButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Entered resetButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");

            // TODO - Reset data to default values
            mTitleText.setText("");
            setDefaultDateTime();
            mDefaultStatusButton.setChecked(true);
            mDefaultPriorityButton.setChecked(true);
        }
    });

    // Set up OnClickListener for the Submit Button

    final Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Entered submitButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");

            // gather ToDoItem data

            // TODO - Get the current Priority
            Priority priority = getPriority();

            // TODO - Get the current Status
            Status status = getStatus();

            // TODO - Get the current ToDoItem Title
            String titleString = getToDoTitle();

            // Construct the Date string
            String fullDate = dateString + " " + timeString;

            // Package ToDoItem data into an Intent
            Intent data = new Intent();
            ToDoItem.packageIntent(data, titleString, priority, status,
                    fullDate);

            // TODO - return data Intent and finish
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,data);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

// Do not modify below this point.

private void setDefaultDateTime() {

    // Default is current time + 7 days
    mDate = new Date();
    mDate = new Date(mDate.getTime() + SEVEN_DAYS);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(mDate);

    setDateString(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    dateView.setText(dateString);

    setTimeString(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

    timeView.setText(timeString);
}

private static void setDateString(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

    // Increment monthOfYear for Calendar/Date -> Time Format setting
    monthOfYear++;
    String mon = "" + monthOfYear;
    String day = "" + dayOfMonth;

    if (monthOfYear < 10)
        mon = "0" + monthOfYear;
    if (dayOfMonth < 10)
        day = "0" + dayOfMonth;

    dateString = year + "-" + mon + "-" + day;
}

private static void setTimeString(int hourOfDay, int minute, int mili) {
    String hour = "" + hourOfDay;
    String min = "" + minute;

    if (hourOfDay < 10)
        hour = "0" + hourOfDay;
    if (minute < 10)
        min = "0" + minute;

    timeString = hour + ":" + min + ":00";
}

private Priority getPriority() {

    switch (mPriorityRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
    case R.id.lowPriority: {
        return Priority.LOW;
    }
    case R.id.highPriority: {
        return Priority.HIGH;
    }
    default: {
        return Priority.MED;
    }
    }
}

private Status getStatus() {

    switch (mStatusRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
    case R.id.statusDone: {
        return Status.DONE;
    }
    default: {
        return Status.NOTDONE;
    }
    }
}

private String getToDoTitle() {
    return mTitleText.getText().toString();
}


// DialogFragment used to pick a ToDoItem deadline date

public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        setDateString(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

        dateView.setText(dateString);
    }

}

// DialogFragment used to pick a ToDoItem deadline time

public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, true);
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        setTimeString(hourOfDay, minute, 0);

        timeView.setText(timeString);
    }
}

private void showDatePickerDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

private void showTimePickerDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
}
```

### ToDoItem

```
package course.labs.todomanager;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.content.Intent;

public class ToDoItem {

public static final String ITEM_SEP = System.getProperty("line.separator");

public enum Priority {
    LOW, MED, HIGH
};

public enum Status {
    NOTDONE, DONE
};

public final static String TITLE = "title";
public final static String PRIORITY = "priority";
public final static String STATUS = "status";
public final static String DATE = "date";
public final static String FILENAME = "filename";

public final static SimpleDateFormat FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);

private String mTitle = new String();
private Priority mPriority = Priority.LOW;
private Status mStatus = Status.NOTDONE;
private Date mDate = new Date();

ToDoItem(String title, Priority priority, Status status, Date date) {
    this.mTitle = title;
    this.mPriority = priority;
    this.mStatus = status;
    this.mDate = date;
}

// Create a new ToDoItem from data packaged in an Intent

ToDoItem(Intent intent) {

    mTitle = intent.getStringExtra(ToDoItem.TITLE);
    mPriority = Priority.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra(ToDoItem.PRIORITY));
    mStatus = Status.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra(ToDoItem.STATUS));

    try {
        mDate = ToDoItem.FORMAT.parse(intent.getStringExtra(ToDoItem.DATE));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        mDate = new Date();
    }
}

public String getTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    mTitle = title;
}

public Priority getPriority() {
    return mPriority;
}

public void setPriority(Priority priority) {
    mPriority = priority;
}

public Status getStatus() {
    return mStatus;
}

public void setStatus(Status status) {
    mStatus = status;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return mDate;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    mDate = date;
}

// Take a set of String data values and 
// package them for transport in an Intent

public static void packageIntent(Intent intent, String title,
        Priority priority, Status status, String date) {

    intent.putExtra(ToDoItem.TITLE, title);
    intent.putExtra(ToDoItem.PRIORITY, priority.toString());
    intent.putExtra(ToDoItem.STATUS, status.toString());
    intent.putExtra(ToDoItem.DATE, date);

}

public String toString() {
    return mTitle + ITEM_SEP + mPriority + ITEM_SEP + mStatus + ITEM_SEP
            + FORMAT.format(mDate);
}

public String toLog() {
    return "Title:" + mTitle + ITEM_SEP + "Priority:" + mPriority
            + ITEM_SEP + "Status:" + mStatus + ITEM_SEP + "Date:"
            + FORMAT.format(mDate);
}

}
```

### ToDoListAdapter

```
package course.labs.todomanager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask.Status;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ToDoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final List<ToDoItem> mItems = new ArrayList<ToDoItem>();
private final Context mContext;

private static final String TAG = "Lab-UserInterface";

public ToDoListAdapter(Context context) {

    mContext = context;

}

// Add a ToDoItem to the adapter
// Notify observers that the data set has changed

public void add(ToDoItem item) {

    mItems.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

// Clears the list adapter of all items.

public void clear() {

    mItems.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

// Returns the number of ToDoItems

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return mItems.size();

}

// Retrieve the number of ToDoItems

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {

    return mItems.get(pos);

}

// Get the ID for the ToDoItem
// In this case it's just the position

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {

    return pos;

}

// Create a View for the ToDoItem at specified position
// Remember to check whether convertView holds an already allocated View
// before created a new View.
// Consider using the ViewHolder pattern to make scrolling more efficient
// See: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // TODO - Get the current ToDoItem
    final ToDoItem toDoItem = (ToDoItem) getItem(position);

    // TODO - Inflate the View for this ToDoItem
    // from todo_item.xml
    //RelativeLayout itemLayout = null;

    // TODO - Fill in specific ToDoItem data
    // Remember that the data that goes in this View
    // corresponds to the user interface elements defined
    // in the layout file
    if (convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflator= (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inflator.inflate(R.layout.add_todo, null);
    }
    // TODO - Display Title in TextView
    final TextView titleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleView);
    titleView.setText(toDoItem.getTitle());


    // TODO - Set up Status CheckBox
    final CheckBox statusView = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusCheckBox);
    statusView.setChecked(toDoItem.getStatus()==course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Status.DONE);


    statusView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Entered onCheckedChanged()");

            // TODO - set up an OnCheckedChangeListener, which
            // is called when the user toggles the status checkbox
            if (toDoItem.getStatus().equals(course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Status.DONE)) 
            { 
                  toDoItem.setStatus(course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Status.NOTDONE);  //Change it
            }
            else 
            {
                toDoItem.setStatus(course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Status.DONE); //Change it
            }

        }
    });

    // TODO - Display Priority in a TextView

    final TextView priorityView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priorityView);
    priorityView.setText(toDoItem.getPriority().toString());


    // TODO - Display Time and Date.
    // Hint - use ToDoItem.FORMAT.format(toDoItem.getDate()) to get date and
    // time String

    final TextView dateView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateView);
    dateView.setText(ToDoItem.FORMAT.format(toDoItem.getDate()));


    // Return the View you just created
    return convertView;

}
}
```

### logcat

> 02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at >course.labs.todomanager.ToDoListAdapter.getView(ToDoListAdapter.java:105)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1321)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1633)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at >android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at >android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at >android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at >android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at >android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at >java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at >com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at >com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   02-06 13:11:20.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):    at >dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   02-06 13:11:26.121: I/Process(1288): Sending signal. PID: 1288 SIG: 9

thanks for any help you can offer in advance!

Comment: NullPointerException occurs because you are trying to access resources of something that is not present. In your case if you mention that the line in question is causing the issue, it is because either `titleView` or `toDoItem` object at that point is NULL

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your titleView (with id: priorityView) is located in the layout you inflate the R.layout.add_todo

If that's not the case you should place it there. If that doesn't help please post your layout xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you figured out the solution yet, but you can try to switch the following

```
convertView=inflator.inflate(R.layout.add_todo, null);
```

to

```
convertView=inflator.inflate(R.layout.add_todo, parent);
```

Comment: But will this fix his problem ?

Comment: This is the User Interface Classes lab from coursera Android course, and I was getting the exact same error as the OP did. After searching for the answer (well, the answer for this lab to be specific...), i realized that the second parameter for inflator.inflate() method should not be null.